# Use the return value of a function as the src of a image tag in React

Tags: reactjs

In my React project, I need to send a POST request to an API, the API will respond with an URL, and I want to use this URL as the `src` attribute of an image tag. The following is the conceptual work flow, which of course does not work. I wonder what is the correct way to write the code. Any help are highly appreciated!

```
const handlePostRequest = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('https://api.com', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: '',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        });

        const responseData = await response.json();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error during POST request: ', error.message);
    }
    
    return responseData;
};

ImgSrc = handlePostRequest();

return (
    <img
        key={innerIndex}
        src={ImgSrc}
        title={image.title}
        className="m-3"
        loading="lazy"
        alt={category}        
    />
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code:

1. `handlePostRequest` is `async` and you're not awaiting it
2. You're defining `responseData` in the `try` block but returning it outside the `try/catch` block where it doesn't exist

To make this work in a React-friendly way, you'd need to use a stateful variable with `useState` and introduce a loading state while your request is in flight, which would be triggered by a `useEffect` on mount.

```
import { useState } from "react";

function MyImage() {
  const [src, setSrc] = useState();

  const handlePostRequest = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('https://api.com', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: '',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      });

      const responseData = await response.json();
      setSrc(responseData);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error during POST request: ', error.message);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    handlePostRequest();
  }, []);

  if (!src) return <p>Loading...</p>

  return (
    <img src={src} loading="lazy" />
  );
}
```

Comment: Variables inside try aren't block scoped. But catch is block scoped. https://medium.com/@roy.gopal1992/things-to-dont-know-about-try-catch-finally-c4165126e934

Comment: I don't believe that is right, try it in MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

Answer (score 1):

the issue is happening because the value of handlePostRequest has been assigned to the variable before it's resolved. You can fix the issue as follows: if you are sending a GET request, then you can follow the implementation mentioned by @emeraldsanto using a useEffect. However, a correction has to be mentioned in that answer because variables inside a try block can be accessed outside

```
const [imgSrc, setImgSrc] = useState();
const handlePostRequest = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('https://api.com', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: '',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        });

        const responseData = await response.json();
        setImgSrc(responseData)
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error during POST request: ', error.message);
    }
};

return (
    imgSrc && <img
        key={innerIndex}
        src={imgSrc}
        title={image.title}
        className="m-3"
        loading="lazy"
        alt={category}        
    />
);
```

This would re-render the DOM once the data is fetched, and the image will be shown via the img tag.

Tip: Usually, most React developers use lowerCamelCase to name variable names, and UpperCamelCase is used only to define components and their files.