# Using a HTTP response as the src of an image tag in a second level function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Similar to in [Use the return value of a function as the src of a image tag in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78111441/use-the-return-value-of-a-function-as-the-src-of-a-image-tag-in-react/78111508#78111508), in my React project, I need to send the POST request to an API and use the response as the `src` of an image tag. Differently, the image tag is in a second-level function, which makes things tricky.

Specifically, I need to use the response of the POST request as the src of the image tag, but the image tag is created in a second-level function and will be returned as a `React.fragment`.

The following code would run but the `src` of the image tag is empty. I think it is because `createImage()` and `handlePostRequest()` runs synchronously thus `createImage()` will not wait for the POST response. But if I put `useEffect()` inside `createImage()`, it throws a "*rendered less hooks*" error because I think `useEffect()` can't be used in a second level function. I have also tried to set `createImage()` as a `async` function and directly send the POST request within this function, but I got a different error: "*Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.*"

I wonder what is the correct way to implement this function. Thanks!

```
import { useState } from "react";

function MyImage() {
  const [imgSrc, setImgSrc] = useState();

  const handlePostRequest = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('https://api.com', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: '',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      });

      const responseData = await response.json();
      setImgSrc(responseData);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error during POST request: ', error.message);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    handlePostRequest();
  }, []);

  const createImage = () => {
    // other code...
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <img src={imgSrc}/>         
        </React.Fragment>
    );
  }


  return (
    <other HTML content/>
    {createImage}
  );
}
```

Comment: I made some silly mistake to the other part of my code, making this code does not work properly. The above code actually works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this issue, you can adjust your implementation to ensure that `createImage` is called after the state has been updated with the new image source.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function MyImage() {
  const [imgSrc, setImgSrc] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const handlePostRequest = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch('https://api.com', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: '',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        });

        const responseData = await response.json();
        setImgSrc(responseData);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error during POST request: ', error.message);
      }
    };

    handlePostRequest();
  }, []);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {imgSrc && <img src={imgSrc} alt="Image" />}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default MyImage;
```

Comment: Thanks but this does not work. The result is the image tag is not created in the webpage at all.

Comment: Hey SAM. try the edited answer's code now.

Comment: Hi ADITYA, thanks for the response, however, I have to keep the  createImage( ) function because the image tag is not the only HTML blob I am going to generate. I only listed part of the code that is relevant to my question.